# Custom field / force password change

Tags: django, security, django-rest-framework, jwt

I need to force a user to change password in a Django application, and specifically a rest-based application. Django is using rest_framework and simplejwt.

I was able to implement a custom claim view as specified [Here](https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt#customizing-token-claims)

My plan was to add a custom user model with a flag, and if the user did not change the password after its first access, the app would return

```
'must_change_password':true
```

However I get no added field.

Any ideas or experiences around this concept would be greatly appreciated.